# Functions return undefined

Tags: javascript

I have getGlobalOptionSetTextByValue function defined in file 1. this function returns a value.  I am calling this function from file 2 but the return value seems to get set with undefined all the time.

Below is the code from file 2:

```
var X= X|| { __namespace: true };
X.TravelHistory = ( function () {
    //This function will calculate the duration and sent an error message if the duration is greater than 6 months.
    function TravelDuration( fromDate, toDate ) {
        var crtlDate = Xrm.Page.getControl( toDate );
        var toDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute( toDate ).getValue();
        var fromDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute( fromDate ).getValue();
        var optionSet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute( "dads_javascriptoptionset" );
        var notification;
        if ( toDate != null && fromDate != null ) {
            var temp1 = new Array();
            temp1 = toDate.split( '/' ); // split the To date with '/'
            var toYear = temp1[0];
            var toMonth = temp1[1];

            var temp2 = new Array();
            temp2 = fromDate.split( '/' ); // split the From date with '/'
            var fromYear = temp2[0];
            var fromMonth = temp2[1];
            //To year have to be less than From year
            if ( toYear < fromYear ) {
                //crtlDate.setNotification( "TO Date needs to be later than the FROM date." );
                notification = X.Common.getGlobalOptionSetTextByValue( 450640028, optionSet );
                crtlDate.setNotification( notification );

            }
        }
    }
    return {
        TravelDuration: function ( fromDate, toDate ) {
            TravelDuration( fromDate, toDate );
        }
    };
})();
```

Below is the code from file 1:

```
var X= X|| { __namespace: true };
X.Common = ( function () {
    var label;
    function getGlobalOptionSetTextByValue( value, optionSetLogicalName ) {
        var globalOptionSet = optionSetLogicalName
        var entityLogicalName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

        for ( var i = 0; i < globalOptionSet.getOptions().length; i++ ) {
            if ( globalOptionSet.getOptions()[i].value == value ) {
                label = globalOptionSet.getOptions()[i].text;
                break;
            }
        }
        return label;
    }
    return {
        getGlobalOptionSetTextByValue: function(value, optionSetLogicalName) {
            getGlobalOptionSetTextByValue(value, optionSetLogicalName);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: You code is not very easy to follow :-( What isn't doing what?

Comment: Why do you have 2 functions on 2 separate pages? It reminds me of C++...

Comment: The path this set of javascript files is taking is not clear to me since you are calling the same function in both files. I don't know exactly where you are starting and where the end is in terms of your plan. Also, I would try putting `console.log()` in a few places of your code so you can find exactly where it goes wrong and becomes undefined.

Comment: globalOptionSet.getOptions()[i].value what is the value of this line?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Also, you can simplify your returns with things like `return { TravelDuration: TravelDuration }`. No need to call the function from another function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object returned by `Xrm.Page.getAttribute( "dads_javascriptoptionset" );` does not contain an entry with the value like

```
{
 id: 450640028,
 text: "....whatever..."
}
```